# Aspose HTML to PDF conversion- hyperlinks to content on same file not working

Tags: c#, .net, html-to-pdf, pdf-conversion, aspose.pdf

I am using AsposePDF for .Net version 17.3 for bulk conversion of lot of html files to PDF. I have an existing html file with hyperlinks to content in same file. Below is a sample of the html in the file.
**Link:**

```
<a href="#bg880016">Section 5</a>
```

**Content:**

```
<a name="#bg880016"><p>section 5 content is here</p></a>
```

When this is converted to PDF the local links are not working anymore. Below is the conversion code:

```
public Stream ConvertHtmlToPDF(Stream inputStream, string docTitle)
{
    Stream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
    inputStream.Position = 0;
    var options = new HtmlLoadOptions();
    var pdfDocument = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(inputStream, options);
    pdfDocument.Info.Title = docTitle;
    pdfDocument.Save(pdfStream);
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. I have also posted a [question](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/837388/html-to-pdf-conversion-hyperlinks-to-content-on-same-file-not-working/showthread.aspx#837388) in their support forum.

Answer (score 1):

I've found you need to convert it first to a Word document and then convert that to a PDF to get it to work as desired.  Do you have Aspose.Words also?

Comment: No. I only have Aspose PDF license. But its strange that i need to convert to a doc first to get this working. This seems to be a fairly common use case if you are converting an html. Have you done this conversion to word to acheive this?

Comment: Yes, I have a lot of experience with Aspose and have done that conversion to word and then to PDF where the local links work.  Unfortunately, where Aspose is concerned, you have to get used to "strange".  Luckily, if you're patient and persistent (and have paid for their priority support), you can usually demonstrate bugs or deficiencies and get them to fix them.

Comment: Aspose.Pdf for .NET is having issue with inline anchor tag and team is working on fixing it. However if you can please share HTML which can help us to test the scenario and during the investigation, we will definitely fix this scenario.

My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.